# Include (bundle) a JRE within the NetBeans Installer?

Tags: installation, bundle, netbeans-7, java

I developed a Java Swing application on the NetBeans Platform (RCP). I want to include the Windows JRE with the installer that NetBeans generates in case a PC does not have JRE installed, but I do not know how to do this. I have tried to follow the following instructions but failed (I find that the instructions assume that you know absolutely everything on JDK and JRE, for example I would get the message 'pack200' is not recognized as an internal or external command...it would seem that some paths are wrong or outdated):

[How to bundle JVM (JRE/JDK) in the installer bundle?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBIBundledJVM)

[Including the JRE in a NetBeans Platform Installer](http://netbeans.dzone.com/including-jre-in-nbi)

[Installing the JRE via an Application's Installer via Windows](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/installing_the_jre_via_an)

I am trying to pack the JRE version 7u7

My JDK folder structure is the following:
C:\Program Files\Java\

in here I have the following two folders:
**jdk1.7.0_07** and **jre7**

Please help me...Thank you so much

Comment: A better overall strategy would be to ensure the end user has the necessary minimum of Java installed using the `deployJava.js`.  That way, when the JRE you decide to bundle is found to have a security bug and is replaced, the application distributable does not need to be regenerated.  Then go on to launch the Swing GUI direct from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: is this for desktop applications or web applets, or both? also, there are situations where this desktop application will be used in environments that do not have internet access.

Comment: *"is this for desktop applications or web applets, or both?"*  I think I covered that pretty well in the info. page linked earlier. *"also, there are situations where this desktop application will be used in environments that do not have internet access."*  It will require internet or network access.  There are more Java capable machines today that have network access, than have removable disks (for loading software off CD/DVD).

Comment: "There are more Java capable machines today that have network access, than have removable disks (for loading software off CD/DVD)." I agree with this, but the application I am developing will be used on the machines that do not have any network access (ex special government, military environments).

Comment: This link http://netbeans.dzone.com/including-jre-in-nbi that you have included in your list seems to cover this quite extensively. Why don't you post the real problems you have or why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have followed "**Installing the JRE via an Application's Installer via Windows**" in your link to successfully create a Windows installer for my Netbeans platform application. 
What are the problems you encountered?

"*'pack200' is not recognized as an internal or external command*" is because %JAVA_HOME%/bin is not in your PATH (environment variable). You can run pack200 with 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\pack200" -J-Xmx1024m rt.jar.pack.gz rt.jar

Btw, it seems like "app.conf=nbproject/my.conf" part in the article is outdated. I have to modify directly the file "build/launcher/etc/*app_name*.conf" in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this guide can help you:

Self-Contained Applications: Package non-JavaFX application
https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7#3

*One of popular questions people ask about self-contained applications - can i package my Java application as self-contained application? Absolutely.
This is true even for tools shipped with JDK 7 update 6. Simply follow steps for [creating package for Swing application with integrated JavaFX content](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_swing_apps_with_integrated) and they will work even if your application does not use JavaFX.*

Comment: its always good if you quote whatever you are referencing, as links broke often, making answers losing its ground.