# What is the preferred way to deploy a jar to people who don't have java?

Tags: java, swing, deployment

I have a program which is being distributed to companies where java is either not allowed on their computers or not allowed to be updated for various security reasons.  It is a java jar as it stands, a simple survey-type desktop program using swing.

My question is, how can I distribute this program to the various end users when they aren't allowed to install anything on their systems, including java?  They will be running the program from a flash drive, so it has to just run from there with no installation or copying to the disk or anything like that, and no guarantee that java will be installed.

All of the target users are on windows, at least, so an exe is an option.

EDIT: Based on what Rob has said, does anyone know if distributing a private JRE is possible?  Bundling a JRE which is preinstalled on the flash drive, and then pointing the jar to that?

Comment: "or not allowed to be updated for various security reasons." wtf...

Comment: All I mean is, there is no guarantees their installation of java will be there or be up to date, and as such I need a way to distribute the program in which it is runnable independent of their setup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include (bundle) a JRE within the NetBeans Installer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976767/include-bundle-a-jre-within-the-netbeans-installer)  Look also for installer technologies that "bundle a JRE". Will require some research to find a solution that does not require admin privileges to install the JVM.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263940/creating-a-windows-exe-from-a-runnable-jar-preferably-on-linux

Comment: launch4j SEEMS to be the solution for me.  Working on all machines tested so far.  Would you like to answer it so I can accept?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is anyway to do this using Java.  The role of the JVM is to interpret the java byte code into instructions which will function on the device which the JVM is installed on.  If no JVM is installed, your intermediate code (JAR file) can't be run.

You may look into distributing your app via ClickOnce if .Net development is an option.  It will allow Windows users to install and run applications with limited permissions even without administrative access on their computers.

Comment: Is there no way to add a private JRE to the flash drive which the program can utilize independent of the user's machine?

Comment: use need a java standalone wrapper like jssmooth.

Comment: You may be able to do this.  You would need to install java to the flash drive and make a .bat file which would set the path appropriately, then run java against your jar.  Just remember to have it clean up the path when it's done.